# Changing parsed arguments ($argv) for native getopt in PHP

Tags: php, command-line-interface, argv, getopt

I have two PHP scripts for command line use:

1. standalone.php: a standalone script using the native [getopt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) function.
2. shell-loop.php: a shell-like interface that repeatedly reads a line, exits if necessary, otherwise passes the input with some additions defined in this 'shell'-environment to the standalone script called through inclusion

As the standalone script uses getopt() I would like to change the argument list it parses in the shell-loop script right before inclusion. I have tried setting $argv and $_SERVER['argv'] (argc respectively) to the new values but it seems getopt() does not read those variables, but - so I assume - it accesses the arguments passed to php directly. (Unless I made some silly mistake..)

**So my question would be**: can the argument list used by getopt() easily be altered from within a php script and how so? If not, for curiosity's sake, I would also wonder if there is a dirty way to do it?

shell-loop.php:

```
do {
    echo "> ";
    
    $cmd = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    if (in_array($cmd,array('exit','bye')))
    {
        break;
    }

    $argv = explode(' ',$cmd);
    
    // .. add some options here
    array_unshift($argv,'--option1');
    array_unshift($argv,'--option2');
    // ...

    $argc = count($argv);
        
    $_SERVER['argv'] = $argv; 
    $_SERVER['argc'] = $argc;

    // standalone.php relies on getopt() to get any optional parameters
    include __DIR__ . '/standalone.php';
    
} while(true);
```

and var_dump($GLOBALS) before the include (with actual arguments):

```
array(10) {
  ["GLOBALS"]=>
  *RECURSION*
  ["argv"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "bt.php"  <- inserted option
    [1]=>
    string(4) "--nl" <- inserted option
    [2]=>
    string(1) "-" <- inserted option
    [3]=>
    string(2) "on"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "A1"
  }
  ["argc"]=>
  &int(5)
  .. GET POST etc here ..
  ["_SERVER"]=>
  array(30) {
    .. many things here ..
    ["argv"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "bt.php"  <- inserted option
      [1]=>
      string(4) "--nl"  <- inserted option
      [2]=>
      string(1) "-"  <- inserted option
      [3]=>
      string(2) "on"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "A1"
    }
    ["argc"]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
```

The third-party getopt class as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193034/how-to-get-advanced-usage-of-getop-in-php-like-python-argparse) would do the job, yes.

I'll look up php's getopt implementation when I get the time, but thought it might be interesting to have the question answered here..

Structurally this approach makes sense in my case, but yes I could do it differently.

Comment: Just wondering, did you try setting `$GLOBALS['argv']` or `$GLOBALS['argc']`?

Comment: Ah, although I kind of did forget, `$GLOBALS['argv']` is also referenced through `$argv`, so it implicitly was set, yes.